# Brightness issue

Tags: laptop, brightness

I need help with my laptop brightness; it is a Huawei Matebook 13.

The <kbd>Fn1</kbd> and <kbd>Fn2</kbd> key bindings for brightness do not work, but the volume ones do work.

I tried with `xrandr --output eDP --brightness 1` and many other solutions found in forums but them only makes my screen looking whiter, not increasing brightness.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1352958/edit) your question.

Comment: Try the utility "light", available in software center. If that helps, you could at least bind a key to this command to set brightness.